# Mac app store -- trying to get encryption to work . . . what am I missing?

Tags: security, validation, macos, encryption, app-store

I am trying to use Alan Quartermain's solution as linked from this question, [Mac App Store Receipt Validation Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261348/mac-app-store-receipt-validation-code)  I keep running into a bunch of unknown symbol errors at link time.  Here are some of the unknown symbols:  `_BIO_new`, `_BIO_ctrl_`, `_EVP_sha1`, `_X509_STORE_free`.  Can anyone clue me in to what I need to do to get rid of these errors?

Things I have done:

- Install OS X 10.6.7 combo update
- Install Xcode 3.2.5
- Install Xcode Developer Tools 1.1
- Link frameworks:

  - Security;
  - SecurityFoundation;
  - SecurityInterface;
  - IOKit;
  - CoreServices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the symbols you’ve listed are exported by libcrypto, which is part of OpenSSL. Have you tried linking libcrypto as well? You can do that by editing your project settings, Build tab, Other Linker Flags, and specifying `-lcrypto`.

Comment: Excellent.  Answer that at the linked question, and I'll gladly award you the bounty there.

Comment: @William I’ve just added a comment there to help others who might be reading that question and have the same problem as you.