# Is anyone able to perform Receipt validation?

Tags: cocoa, mac-app-store, receipt

Is anyone now online able to perform receipt validation in a Mac application?

1. Have you used the ASN generated files in the application?
2. Are you able to produce a sample receipt by automatic popup of the iTunes authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know to check receipts is by letting [Receigen](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/receigen/id452840086) generate the code - different for each new version. It's probably more secure than what you can develop in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, but i am using open source code to do it.
Using this code in your main , and changing your app bundleID/version, it validates the receipt.

In this question you can see the code i used.

[Mac App Store Receipt Validation Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261348/mac-app-store-receipt-validation-code)

Answer (score 0):

I've got an example receipt at my question here ([Can Purely On-Device In-App Purchase Receipt Validation Be Done With iOS6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461064/can-purely-on-device-in-app-purchase-receipt-validation-be-done-with-ios6)). I've generated the ASN files and am trying to use them now. I used the [compiler here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asn1c/). I'm not sure if it all works though, just starting testing in earnest now.

Chris.