# equivalent to transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

is this code from iOS 6 (SKPaymentTransaction)

```
transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes
```

completely equivalent to this from iOS 7?

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]]
```

in terms of content?

thanks

Comment: Are you asking if the receipts from iOS6 are identical in content to the receipts from iOS7?

Comment: yes and also if the NSData you obtain by the first line is the same you obtain from the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS6 and iOS7 receipts are different. Apple changed the receipt format when going to iOS7 in an effort to improve security. Take a look at: [Can Purely On-Device In-App Purchase Receipt Validation Be Done With iOS6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461064/can-purely-on-device-in-app-purchase-receipt-validation-be-done-with-ios6) and [iOS7 - receipts not validating at sandbox - error 21002 (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222845/ios7-receipts-not-validating-at-sandbox-error-21002-java-lang-illegalargume/19963192#19963192).

If you are talking about using these two methods on iOS7, in my tests, both return iOS7 style receipts. I'm not sure if the receipts are byte by byte identical, however.

Note that transactionReceipt is deprecated in iOS7.

Comment: *Note that transactionReceipt is deprecated in iOS7.*  ... this is why I am asking... :)

Comment: It took me quite a while to figure out that the receipt formats differ. I found that it wasn't quite clearly enough stated in the docs. And as you say, it would have been nice for the docs to state that, even though deprecated, transactionReceipt returns something quite different in iOS7!

Comment: yes, that is why I have asked. Apple is famous for vague, crappy or incomplete docs, or all the 3 together. I hate every piece of documentation they ever wrote. If it was not for sites like this, most part of programmers would not be able to code a single line.