# Mac app - check App Store receipt

Tags: cocoa, validation, app-store, receipt

Many of the possible duplicates seem to address methods of updating apps both normally and via App Store.

This one mentions a few working solutions:

[Mac App Store Receipt Validation Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261348/mac-app-store-receipt-validation-code)

for programmers like me who want to not reinvent the wheel from the Apple Docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/_index.html

My problem is that I'm having a hard time finding finished "libraries" that work.

I would simply like to know if anyone has had success with any of these open-source projects and whether any of them are particularly easy to use.