# Receipt validation issue in App Purchases Mac Store "Receipt validation should be presented..."

Tags: cocoa, in-app-purchase, storekit

My applications uses the Store Kit API to purchases in app purchases. I am getting the following store rejection issue, has anyone ever encountered this?

> 2.3 Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected
>
> The app is not using the Store Kit API properly. The application needs to use receipt     validation in order for Store Kit to properly
>   process In App Purchases.

I inquired further and they said:

> Receipt validation should be presented on launch of the app.

Anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

See the following:

[Mac App Store Receipt Validation Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261348/mac-app-store-receipt-validation-code)

This app is helpful as well but to pricy IMO:

http://receigen.etiemble.com/